# How to toggle audio playback using GPIO push button?

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I want to play and pause an audio file using the same push button. What will be the solution of this problem? Please help me. I am using 'aplay', which player has such feature of toggling?
here is the python code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import subprocess
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) 
while True:
    input_state1=GPIO.input(17)
    if input_state1==False:
        subprocess.call(["aplay", "temp.wav"])
```

Comment: Request you to be more specific - what have you tried so far? What environment are you using, if raspberry-pi is the platform, where is the code, etc.

Comment: Please check my post @nj2237 . I have edited it.

Comment: While searching i found a command ' mpc toggle' . If anyone has any idea about it?

Comment: I have added an answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are configuring an input pin, and this is what you are doing so far:

- when pin is pressed, `input_state1` will be `True`, and you do not do anything.
- when pin is not pressed, `input_state1` will be `False` and you are playing the `temp.wav` file using `aplay` (command-line sound recorder and player for ALSA).

Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I understand your intention is to play and pause using the GPIO pin as a toggle (ie. when pressed, it should play if it is paused, or pause if it is playing).

After a little searching, it looks like `aplay` cannot pause and resume like you would want to. If you still want to use this, you can use this aplay wrapper for Node.js called [Node-aplay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aplay) which supports this. Easier way is to use [mpc](https://www.mankier.com/1/mpc), you'd have to first install it and and set it up. After that, you can try this code to do the toggling:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import subprocess
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# this method is invoked when the event occurs
def toggle_state(channel):
    subprocess.call(["mpc", "toggle"]) # toggles between play and pause

# detects GPIO pin press event
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH, toggle_state, 600)

try:
    subprocess.call(["mpc", "add", "temp.wav"]) # adds file to the playlist
    subprocess.call(["mpc", "play"]) # starts playing (may need to mention position)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup() # clean up GPIO settings before exiting
```

As you can see, I have added `GPIO.add_event_detect` to detect the GPIO being pressed (read more about this API [here](http://tieske.github.io/rpi-gpio/modules/GPIO.html#add_event_callback)). I have put some comments against what the code does too. Hope this helps!

Comment: The above program simply plays the audio while exiting from the python script. No more input from button is working as it has exited the script.